# JSON image importing

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add 4 images on my site however the images are not loading. I can see 4 images in the inspector tool, however they are not showing up.

This is my code in JS:

```
function createZooland(zoolandData) {
    let content = document.getElementById("content");

let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
let blockquote = document.createElement("blockquote");
let img = document.createElement("img");

h2.innerHTML = `${zoolandData[0].common_name}`;
content.appendChild(h2);

h3.innerHTML = `${zoolandData[0].scientific_name}`;
content.appendChild(h3);

blockquote.innerHTML = `${zoolandData[0].description}`; 
content.appendChild(blockquote);

for(let i = 0; i < zoolandData.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < zoolandData[i].images["image"].length; j++){
        img.src = "images/" + `${zoolandData[0].images.image}`;
        

        content.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

}

and this is the JSON it's referencing:

```
{
            "common_name": "Koala",
            "scientific_name": "Phascolarctos cinereus",
            "description": "Koalas are well-known...",
            "images": {
                "image": [
                    "koala1.jpg",
                    "koala2.jpg",
                    "koala3.jpg",
                    "koala4.jpg"
                ]
            }
        },
```

Please let me know if any additional information is needed. I'm not sure how to get the images to display.

Comment: For one you need to move `img = document.createElement("img");` inside the loop

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix my problem. :( thanks though.

Comment: Use the inspector to see what the HTML is. Can you write the HTML manually to get the same effect? Do that, then work backwards to figure out what the JS should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `img = document.createElement("img");` inside the loop

Or just do this

```js
const zoolandData = [{ "common_name": "Koala", "scientific_name": "Phascolarctos cinereus", "description": "Koalas are well-known...", "images": { "image": [ "koala1.jpg", "koala2.jpg", "koala3.jpg", "koala4.jpg" ] } }, { "common_name": "Dwarf wallaby", "scientific_name": "Notamacropus dorcopsulus", "description": "Native to New Guinea, it is the smallest known wallaby species ...", "images": { "image": [ "wallaby1.jpg", "wallaby2.jpg", "wallaby3.jpg", "wallaby4.jpg" ] } } ];

content.innerHTML += zoolandData
  .map(entry => `<h2>${entry.common_name}</h2>
    <h3>${entry.scientific_name}</h3>
    <blockquote>${entry.description}</blockquote>
    ${entry.images.image
    .map(src => `<img src="images/${src}" alt="${src}" />`).join("")}`
  ).join("")
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```